# Permission denied in denyhosts

Tags: python

Apologies in advance if this is addressed elsewhere (couldn't find anything) or is a simple Python issue. I'm Python-ignorant.

I'm running the default install of denyhosts under Fedora 20. I keep getting the following error:

```
2014-02-17 02:20:05,644 - denyfileutil: INFO     purging entries older than: Mon Feb  4 02:20:05 2013
2014-02-17 02:20:05,708 - denyfileutil: INFO     num entries purged: 0
2014-02-17 02:20:05,818 - sync        : ERROR    [Errno 13] Permission denied
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/DenyHosts/sync.py", line 117, in receive_new_hosts
    self.__prefs.get("SYNC_DOWNLOAD_RESILIENCY"))
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1224, in __call__
    return self.__send(self.__name, args)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1578, in __request
    verbose=self.__verbose
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1264, in request
    return self.single_request(host, handler, request_body, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1292, in single_request
    self.send_content(h, request_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/xmlrpclib.py", line 1439, in send_content
    connection.endheaders(request_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 969, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 829, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 791, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/httplib.py", line 772, in connect
    self.timeout, self.source_address)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/socket.py", line 571, in create_connection
    raise err
error: [Errno 13] Permission denied
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: are you trying to bind to a privileged (1 thru 1024) port as a non-root user?  you can't...

Comment: I am not the author of this package, so I could only speculate on how the code operates. However, I would be surprised if it tried to do this without appropriate privileges.

Answer (score 1):

`denyhosts` does not run under Fedora 20, because Fedora 20 has changed how it handles log files. There does not appear to be a workaround at present. See [this mail](http://sourceforge.net/p/denyhosts/mailman/message/32013808/) and [this issue](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=988163).

Recommendation: As root, remove `denyhosts` as follows:

```
systemctl stop denyhosts
systemctl disable denyhosts
yum remove denyhosts
```